# Cannot call a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm experimenting with Box2dWeb, and working with top-down car game.

My problem arises when I try to control the car, so it will move, at first only forwards. For simplicity I don't want to use wheels, and just apply the force to the car (a box).

For the controls I made a function for but for a reason it's not getting called... That's where I need a pointer or advice. (Creation and placement of objects works just fine)

Here's part of the code:

```
var GlobalVar={   }
var KEY = {
    UP: 87,//W
    DOWN: 83,//s
    LEFT: 65,//A
    RIGHT: 68//D
}        
GlobalVar.pressedKeys = [];//an array to remember which key is pressed or not

$(function(){
   $(document).keydown(function(e){
     GlobalVar.pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
 });
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  GlobalVar.pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
 });

Rendering();
PlaceStuff(GlobalVar.currentLevel);//placing stuff, like car and boundaries/walls
moveCar();

});
function moveCar(){
 if (GlobalVar.pressedKeys[KEY.UP]){
   var force = new b2Vec2(0, -10000000);
   GlobalVar.car.ApplyForce(force, GlobalVar.car.GetWorldCenter());
  }
}
```

Comment: `moveCar` only gets called once at the start of the program. Basically, you're never checking if the car should move after startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the `moveCar` function is being called more than once.

You should do the following:

```
function moveCar(){

   if (GlobalVar.pressedKeys[KEY.UP]){
       var force = new b2Vec2(0, -10000000);
       GlobalVar.car.ApplyForce(force, GlobalVar.car.GetWorldCenter());
    }


    requestAnimationFrame(moveCar);

}
```

---

You may also want to add a modifier to modify the amount of force added depending on the frame rate:

```
then = Date.now();

function moveCar(){

    var now = Date.now();
    var modifier = now - then; // Make modifier the time in milliseconds it took since moveCar was last executed.

    then = now;

   if (GlobalVar.pressedKeys[KEY.UP]){
       var force = new b2Vec2(0, -10000000);
       GlobalVar.car.ApplyForce(force * modifier, GlobalVar.car.GetWorldCenter());
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(moveCar);

}
```

This will ensure the car doesn't move slower on slower systems.

---

If you also want the `Rendering()` function to be executed more than once, you may also want to create another function which gets called as often as possible and calls the other two functions.

```
then = Date.now();

function moveCar(modifier){
   if (GlobalVar.pressedKeys[KEY.UP]){
       var force = new b2Vec2(0, -10000000);
       GlobalVar.car.ApplyForce(force * modifier, GlobalVar.car.GetWorldCenter());
    }
}

function update() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var modifier = now - then; // Make modifier the time in milliseconds it took since moveCar was last executed.

    then = now;

    moveCar(modifier);
    Rendering();

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you only call `moveCall` once, but you probably want to do it after each key press:

```
$(document).on('keydown keyup', function(e){
    GlobalVar.pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
    moveCar();
});
```